# Get all items from cart

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, products

I have a custom module where I want to get all items from the cart and take a custom attribute(days_to_dispatch), but I don't know why I don't see that attribute and others(description, short_description, etc).
In the block Products.php:

```
protected $checkoutSession;
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

public function getCartProducts(){
        $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
        if (!$this->hasData('quote')) {
            $this->setData('quote', $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote());
        }
        return $this->_getData('quote');
    }
```

And in my phtml file, I put

```
<?php
$quote = $block->getCartProducts();
foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) {
    echo "<pre>"; var_dump($_item->debug());
}
?>
```

but I don't see that attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get Custom Attribute at cart item level, you need to define attribute in  Vendor/Module/etc/catalog_attributes.xml.

refer below Example.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="days_to_dispatch" />
    </group>
</config>
```

You can then write below code to get value.

$product = $item->getProduct()->getDaysToDispatch(); // where item is cart item

Answer (score 1):

**Please try Below Code**
Create a catalog_attributes.xml in Vendor/Module/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
 <group name="quote_item">
     <attribute name="days_to_dispatch"/>
 </group>
</config>
```

Refer Below Code.

```
<?php
$quote = $block->getCartProducts();
foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) {
    $product = $_item->getProduct();
    echo $product->getDaysToDispatch();
    echo "<pre>"; var_dump($_item->debug());
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use class \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart to get data in Cart

```
// Block 

protected $_cart;
    
    public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart)
    {
        $this->_cart = $cart;
    }
    
    public function getItemCollectionInCart(){
        return $this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    }


// Template file

$cart = $block->getItemCollectionInCart();

foreach($cart as $item) {
     echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
      echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
       echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
       echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
      echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';            
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers with xml works well. In meantime I tried another solution that also works, but is not the best one.
In the file Products.php I put:

```
public function getCartProducts(){
        $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
        if (!$this->hasData('quote')) {
            $this->setData('quote', $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote());
        }
        return $this->_getData('quote');
    }
public function getProductById($id)
    {
        return $this->_productFactory->create()->load($id);
    }
```

And in the phtml file I put:

```
$quote = $block->getCartProducts();
$itemsId = [];
$daysToDispatch = [];
foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) {
    $itemsId[] = $_item->getProductId();
    var_dump($_item->debug());
}
foreach($itemsId as $id){
    $prod = $block->getProductById($id);
    echo "<pre>"; var_dump($prod->debug());
}
```